# How do I clear a "bare" cookie (w/o a name *AND* value) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

A third party ad service on a website I'm working on has been setting bare cookies, which then cause problems with parsing other cookies server-side.

What I mean by a bare cookie is one w/o both a name & value

Here is debug output from a session in Developer Tools showing the type of cookie I have (and my attempts to clear) via JS.  Would like a solution to clear these that works on both Chrome & FF at minimum.

This output shows my attempts in Chrome;

```
/* Set normal / name value pairs */
document.cookie = "name=value";
document.cookie = "name2=value2";

/* See document.cookie value  */
console.log(document.cookie);
```

This outputs:

> name=value; name2=value2

```
/* set bare cookie & output document.cookie */
document.cookie = "bare";
console.log(document.cookie);
```

This outputs:

> name=value; name2=value2; bare

```
/* try setting empty -- if empty name? */
document.cookie = "";
console.log(document.cookie);
```

This outputs:

> name=value; name2=value2; bare

```
/* try setting bare with a value */
document.cookie = "bare=value";
console.log(document.cookie);
```

This outputs:

> name=value; name2=value2; bare; bare=value

Notice we still have bare; and bare=value

How to get rid of the bare; in document.cookie listing via JS?

Comment: All cookies should be of the form `name=value`. I think the bare one is invalid.

Comment: That's why it's ignored when you assign `bare=value`, the browser doesn't consider that to be the name of the cookie.

Comment: How is it even possible to create a cookie with no name or value?  I'd complain to the ad service.  If that is not an option (I feel sorry for you), I'd handle it on the server-side instead.

Comment: How is the cookie set in the first place? Via JS, or via HTTP response header? Have you tried deleting it the “usual” way, by setting it again with `;expires=0`?

Comment: _“which then cause problems with parsing other cookies server-side”_ – how so? What exactly do the request headers look like when the browser makes a request including this “bare” cookie?

Comment: Here's some anonymized data seen in the Cookie header from the server-side:   'Cookie' => 'user=12345; user=12345; bare; sessionkey=abc; sessionkey=abc; __utmt=1; __utmt_b=1; __utma=54321'